# Starting the built-in bluetooth discovery activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to start the activity that does the Bluetooth scanning and pairing, as you can get there though the settings on Android.

I have tried looking for this online, but all I found was the `startDiscovery` call of the `BluetoothAdapter`, which means I have to implement broadcastreceivers etc. I will implement those eventually, but for now (I am pressed by time), I just want to call that activity using `startActivity` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Bluetooth.ACTION_SCAN);
startActivity(i);
```

`ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE` is not what I am looking for, as I do not want to become discoverable myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent();
intentBluetooth.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intentBluetooth);
```

you might need this permission: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Answer (score 0):

First you need to browse for nearby bluetooth devices and create an array of that 
you also need the following permissions :

you can try this code it always work for me though it may need some tailoring

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
      BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter  
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  
    textview1.append("\nAdapter: " + btAdapter);  

    CheckBluetoothState();  
  }  

  /* It is called when an activity completes.*/  
  @Override  
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {  
      CheckBluetoothState();  
    }  
  }  

  @Override  
  protected void onDestroy() {  
    super.onDestroy();  
  }  

  private void CheckBluetoothState() {  
    // Checks for the Bluetooth support and then makes sure it is turned on  
    // If it isn't turned on, request to turn it on  
    // List paired devices  
    if(btAdapter==null) {   
      textview1.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");  
      return;  
    } else {  
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {  
        textview1.append("\nBluetooth is enabled...");  

        // Listing paired devices  
        textview1.append("\nPaired Devices are:");  
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();  
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {  
          textview1.append("\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);  
        }  
      } else {  
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth  
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);  
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);  
      }  
    }  
  }
```

i am assuming u have a layout with a textview named textview1